# How can I clean "Age atstart of presidency" column to be like: 57 years, 62 days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract

I have "presidents" dataset from wiki and I want to clean the "Age atstart of presidency" to be like:
57 years, 80 days.
this is a  link for the dataset : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-OlBbONQEvelO5i-epYPj48hRFQbyz-Q/view?usp=sharing

I have tried using a python code in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("presidents.csv")
df["Age atstart of presidency"].str.extract()
```

The problem is that I couldn't define what pattern to pass to the extract function to get the desired result

Comment: Please post the first few lines from your file instead of a link to google drive. Apart from the fact that ppl might be hesitatnt to go to a third-party site, the link might go dead in the future, invalidating your question

Answer (score 0):

I'm keeping a sample of your DataFrame here so in case the dataset link is invalid in the future people would still find it useful. The original DataFrame:

```
           President             Born      Age atstart of presidency        Age atend of presidency Post-presidencytimespan          Died                 Age
1  George Washington  Feb 22, 1732[a]  57 years, 67 daysApr 30, 1789   65 years, 10 daysMar 4, 1797       2 years, 285 days  Dec 14, 1799  67 years, 295 days
2         John Adams  Oct 30, 1735[a]  61 years, 125 daysMar 4, 1797  65 years, 125 daysMar 4, 1801      25 years, 122 days   Jul 4, 1826  90 years, 247 days
3   Thomas Jefferson  Apr 13, 1743[a]  57 years, 325 daysMar 4, 1801  65 years, 325 daysMar 4, 1809      17 years, 122 days   Jul 4, 1826   83 years, 82 days
4      James Madison  Mar 16, 1751[a]  57 years, 353 daysMar 4, 1809  65 years, 353 daysMar 4, 1817      19 years, 116 days  Jun 28, 1836  85 years, 104 days
5       James Monroe     Apr 28, 1758  58 years, 310 daysMar 4, 1817  66 years, 310 daysMar 4, 1825       6 years, 122 days   Jul 4, 1831   73 years, 67 days
```

##### Here's your solution

This will extract both the age and date from start and end of the presidency and add four new columns to the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("presidents.csv")

def extractAge_Date(row):
    
    # extract the age and date from the start of presidency
    age, date = row["Age atstart of presidency"].split('days')
    row['Age at the start of presidency'] = age+'days'
    row['Date at start of presidency'] = date
    
    # extract the age and date from the end of presidency    
    age, date = row["Age atend of presidency"].split('days')
    row['Age at the end of presidency'] = age+'days'
    row['Date at end of presidency'] = date
    return row

df = df.apply(extractAge_Date, axis=1)
print(df.iloc[:,-4:].head())
```

Output:

```
  Age at the start of presidency Date at start of presidency Age at the end of presidency Date at end of presidency
0              57 years, 67 days                Apr 30, 1789            65 years, 10 days               Mar 4, 1797
1             61 years, 125 days                 Mar 4, 1797           65 years, 125 days               Mar 4, 1801
2             57 years, 325 days                 Mar 4, 1801           65 years, 325 days               Mar 4, 1809
3             57 years, 353 days                 Mar 4, 1809           65 years, 353 days               Mar 4, 1817
4             58 years, 310 days                 Mar 4, 1817           66 years, 310 days               Mar 4, 1825
```

##### Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The string portion you want always ends in "days" so you can define a Regex pattern to capture the section with that ending:

```
df["Age atstart of presidency"] = df[Age atstart of presidency"].str.extract(r"(.*days)")
```